# Possibilities for transferring image with text

Tags: iphone, email

I went thru StackOverflow for finding out different solutions for sending/fetching images along with text via iPhone apps. There are few options like:

1-Sending content via Email to other email address(Just like iphone app,**POSTAGE** do)

2-Sending/Receiving in-app SMS but that is only supported in iOS4

3-Use some intermediate Server to send/receive Data.

I was more inclined towards option #2 but did not find ways to accomplish it. Option #3 would be depending on 3rd layer which could go down. I have not found a way to read iPhone's inBox or connecting directly with IMAP server

What would you recommend?I am desperately looking for solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can email images as an attachment using the MFMailComposeViewController class.